# Ruby on Rails 3 dynamic forms that change depending on input

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, dynamic

What is it called when I want to create a form where, depending on input, other fields can either appear or disappear? For example, if I'm filling out a form and it asks my age. If I'm over a certain age, then another field shows up underneath? What is that called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JQuery, for example the show/hide methods. See http://jquery.com/, there is plenty of documentation in the wiki.

Edit: There are of course other libraries or you could go with plain javascript to make your page/forms dynamic. However, JQuery will be default in upcoming Rails 3.1.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I knew it had to be something simple. [Here is a tutorial I found](http://upcomer.wordpress.com/2011/03/22/rails-3-jquery-basics/) that explains how to do it the way I was imagining.

Answer (score 0):

I would call it a "dynamic form" or something similar.